# Shopextension for TYPO3

Tags: typo3

I'm looking for a shop extension. Pay passes in advance, the only thing that would be important, which is an invoice will be generated as PDF, and the buyer will be sent by mail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the developer of the extension Cart (https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/cart). I updated the tcpdf extension yesterday. This is the preparation releasing CartPdf soon (this or next week). The PDF can be configured through TypoScript and HTML-templates.

[preview of an generated PDF in my testing environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTlFB.png)

In the first release version it is possible to generate the invoice PDF in a Backend Module. It is planned that the PDF can be added as an E-Mail-Attachment if the order is payed (e.g. paying with PayPal). But you can also generate PDFs for order confirmations, delivery notes or similar order related documents.

I'm working on some other payment provider too.

If you have further questions you can contact me at typo3.slack.com.